# How to find dollar symbol using regex.h

Tags: c, regex

Below is my code in which i want to find whether string contain `$` symbol or not but it is showing error: `error: unknown escape sequence '\$'`

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_MATCHES 1 //The maximum number of matches allowed in a single string

void match(regex_t *pexp, char *sz) {
        regmatch_t matches[MAX_MATCHES]; //A list of the matches in the string (a list of 1)
        //Compare the string to the expression
        //regexec() returns 0 on match, otherwise REG_NOMATCH
        if (regexec(pexp, sz, MAX_MATCHES, matches, 0) == 0) {
                printf(" matches characters ");
        } else {
                printf(" does not match\n");
        }
}

int main() {
        int rv;
        regex_t exp; //Our compiled expression
        //1. Compile our expression.
        //Our regex is "-?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?". I will explain this later.
        //REG_EXTENDED is so that we can use Extended regular expressions
        rv = regcomp(&exp, "\$", REG_EXTENDED);
        if (rv != 0) {
                printf("regcomp failed with %d\n", rv);
        }
        //2. Now run some tests on it
        match(&exp, "Price of iphone is $800 ");

        //3. Free it
        regfree(&exp);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash:

```
rv = regcomp(&exp, "\\$", REG_EXTENDED);
```

Answer (score 3):

Escape the backslash in the string literal also: "`\\$"`

Answer (score 3):

I haven't done C regex's for some time, but from memory you have to double escape backslashes in them, because the first one is seen as a C escape, the second one is then passed to the regex engine as an escape for the $. i.e. `\\$`

As a further example of that, if you want to check for a backslash in a C regex, you need to use `\\\\`

Answer (score 1):

When you want to create a string which includes a backslash, like this regular expression, you need to escape the backslash with another backslash:

```
regcomp(&exp, "\\$", REG_EXTENDED);
```